# QUERY formula combining multiple cells into one, despite them NOT meeting criteria

Tags: google-sheets

This is the Formula:

=IFERROR(QUERY(Week7_Stats!$B4:$AH,"Select C Where D ='Top' and M > .5 Order by G Desc Limit 6"),"NA")

Now, this WORKS for Weeks 1 through 7, changing (of course) the week # in the formula.

The moment we go to Week 8 the formula suddenly starts merging the top 4 cells in the query range into the first cell despite the fact that they do NOT meet the "Where D = 'Top':

=IFERROR(QUERY(Week8_Stats!$B4:$AH,"Select C Where D ='Top' and M > .5 Order by G Desc Limit 6"),"NA")

I have tried changing the Column letters to Col2 and so on, no success.  If I change the $B4 to $B7 it begins to work again.. however that forces a skip on stats that need to be grabbed.

Suggestions?

Comment: Please share you example copy, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Since we can't see your spreadsheet or data, there isn't much people here will be able to tell you. As has been suggested, share a link to a copy of the spreadsheet or to a realistic sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

**Try** set the `Query` header to `0`

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(Week7_Stats!A:AH,"Select C Where D ='Top' and M > .5 Order by G Desc Limit 6", 0),"NA")
```

Comment: Still pulling a cell that does not match the "Where D = 'Top' " :(